# Draw an OccupancyGrid?

Tags: ros, navigation, visualization, ros-kinetic, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any ROS tools, or recommended third-party tools, for drawing a 2D grid that's output as a nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid? I could find an online grid editor that outputs to coordinates, then convert them, but I'm hoping there's an already-made tool.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301265/draw-an-occupancygrid?/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2018-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:
I haven't used it myself, but if you have access to matlab, it would appear it has some infrastructure that could be helpful with this. See [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/occupancygrid.html).

**Comment by [luk.mitka](https://answers.ros.org/users/37135/luk.mitka/) on 2018-08-23**:
There is a grid_map [library](http://wiki.ros.org/grid_map). I'm using it to edit existing grid maps or creating new from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The map_server loads an image + YAML file to publish a nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid. You can edit the image file in any image editor (e.g. GIMP, Photoshop, etc). The [wiki page for map_server](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server) has details of how to setup the YAML file that tells map_server how to interpret the image.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2018-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0